# browserAction.setBadgeText isn't being executed when used in tabs.executeScript callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first Chrome extension. I have a default popup `popup.html` which loads `popup.js`.

I used serg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4979785/727074) to [Chrome's tabs.executeScript - passing parameters and using libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976996/chromes-tabs-executescript-passing-parameters-and-using-libraries) as inspiration for the popup->page interaction.

The problem is that the following click handler in `popup.js` works:

```
function click(e) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "loading" } );
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"globalVarName = {'scriptOptions': {...}};" },
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/script.js"},
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } ))
    );
    window.close();
}
```

But the following does not:

```
function click(e) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "loading" } );
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"globalVarName = {'scriptOptions': {...}};" },
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/script.js"},
            function(){chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );})
    );
    window.close();
}
```

I want to be able to do more than one thing on completion.

#### Edit:

I've realised that the first case immediately executes `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText()`, not when the script has finished executing. So that case can be ignored. I've reworded the question title to reflect this.

What I'm looking for is why the second case's callback doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Once I got my facts straight, I realized the same thing. Are you sure `script.js` is actually executed without any errors?

Comment: I guessed that :). Yes. Well, it executes most of the time. Sometimes `globalVarName` isn't defined. I can add the contents of `script.js` to the question if you like.

Comment: Are you also sure it executes all the way through? Putting an alert way at the end could help you find that out if you are having trouble with that. I think that experiment is far more useful than posting the code - either it works or it doesn't...

Comment: Hang on though, surely this will never work as you intend, shouldn't your second executeScript be wrapped in an anonymous function? As it's the callback from the initital executeScript??

Comment: @urbananimal ugh the same mistake. That should explain why `globalVarName` isn't defined sometimes.

Comment: @AdamLynch does that fix your problem? I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @urbananimal I'm afraid not. Now `script.js` isn't executing at all.

Comment: Which would suggest there is a problem with the first script you're running?

Comment: @urbananimal The first script is just a variable declaration though. The second script depends on that object too, and it was running fine most of the time.

Comment: I've now simplified the code; `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"var a = 'a';" },
   function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/script.js"});
   }
  );` But it's still not executing.

Comment: OK, the code works for me. There is nothing wrong with the way things are being called. script.js runs for me... Are you getting any errors? Have you set your permissions correctly?

Comment: @urbananimal I took the code I just quoted and began from scratch with that and built back up to what it was. I'm not 100% sure why but it's working now. My best guess is that the `window.close()` at the end of the click handling was causing problems. (It is now if I put it in, but I don't want the popup to close anyway). If you think that makes sense, add it to your answer and I'll accept

Comment: Oh yeah... That would make sense :P I don't know the exact context of your particular application but executeScript is executing the the script in the open tab. Presumably your code is closing the window before the second script is executing... Doh. I won't add it to my answer. You should add it as your own answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the culprit here is `window.close()` which closes the popup. The same popup in which this code is executing (except `script.js`, that's executing on the actual page).

Therefore, the callback was never being executed. I'm only talking of course about case 2 here (see my edit to the question).

My latest fully working code for any future visitors:

```
var tabId = null;
function click(e) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "..." } );
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, 
        {code:"globalVarName= {...}" }, 
        function(){ 
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/script.js"},
                function(){chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "" } ); 
                    }, 1000);
                }
            ); 
        } 
    );
}
```

*Also note that the path to the script (`script.js` here) is relative to the extension source root, i.e. where the `manifest.json` is.*