# passing parameters to chrome.tabs.executescript()

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-frame, chrome-web-store

How can I pass parameters to `chrome.tabs.executescript()`?
I have defined them outside from `chrome.tabs.executescript()`.

Comment: this link can help you : [Passing-Parameters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976996/chromes-tabs-executescript-passing-parameters-and-using-libraries

Comment: please check the below link for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567624/pass-parameter-using-executescript-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make up a string as a small js code to be passed to executescript() first, to add some parameters into global space (or the isolated space of the content scripts) before the real js you want to invoke.