# How can I pass data from an injected content script to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

It's my first time developing a chrome extension, and to be honest, I'm not even sure if this is the right design pattern.

My Chrome extension has a button up in the toolbar. When that button is clicked, I want to toggle an iframe directly into the active webpage.

I got that part working no problem:

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version":         2,
  "description":              "Inject a complete, premade web page",
  "name":                     "Inject whole web page",
  "version":                  "1",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["html/price-snipe-iframe.html"],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/lib/jquery.min.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/action19x19.png",
      "38": "icons/action38x38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Price Sniper"
  }
}
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {
    file: "css/global.css"
  });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "js/lib/jquery.min.js" });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "iframe-injector.js" });

});
```

*iframe-injector.js*

```
var snipeBar = $('#price-snipe-bar');

if (! $('#price-snipe-bar').length) {
  var iFrame  = document.createElement("iframe");
  iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL("html/price-snipe-iframe.html");
  iFrame.id = "price-snipe-bar";
  iFrame.innerHTML = "<h1>GOT IT?</h1>"

  document.body.insertBefore(iFrame, document.body.firstChild);

  $('body').css({ 'margin-top': '43px'});
} else {
  $('#price-snipe-bar').remove();
  $('body').css({ 'margin-top': ''});
}
```

Here I'm simply seeing if the iframe exists, and if doesn't I'm inserting it.

The thing I really need to do here is get the images off of the active or current tab/page, and inject them into the iframe.

Is there a way to do this, or is there a better pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

You create a new `iframe` in the document.

Its origin is `chrome-extension://...`, so it should have full access to the Chrome API.

You can use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from that frame's scripts to contact your content script and request data.

The only tricky thing is to pass along the right tab ID, but you can do it by [passing it to the content script first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567624/pass-parameter-using-executescript-chrome) and then creating a frame with tab ID as parameter in the URL.