# onMessage not being executed on Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567624/pass-parameter-using-executescript-chrome), I am trying to use executeScript or sendMessage to pass a variable to my content.js file. Using Chrome dev tools, I see that it is reaching my content.js file, and it also runs the test alert I insert, but when it gets to the

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
```

it skips it entirely. I'm not sure what is happening here?

popup.js

```
function search() {
    var name = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "jquery.js" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: 'var name = ' + name + ';'
        }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'content.js' });
        });
    });
}
document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', search);
```

or popup.js using sendMessage

```
function search() {
    var name = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "jquery.js" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'content.js' }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage({ name: name });
        });
    });
}
document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', search);
```

content.js

```
alert('hi');
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message.name);
});
```

Comment: And what if you remove the alert? `onMessage` is not triggered if there is a blocking dialog in the content script: https://crbug.com/456482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing a different answer I found on SO (cant find it atm), I was missing a function to pass the tab id to the content script.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {'type': type, 'name': name });
});
```