# How can I copy the page title to clipboard from a context menu option?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to do a Firefox WebExtension to copy the page title to clipboard when I select a context menu option, but it doesn't work.
I've seen these examples: [context-menu-demo](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/context-menu-demo) and [selection-to-clipboard](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/selection-to-clipboard).
But:

1. If I create a context menu with a `background` script I can't [copy to clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Browser-specific_considerations).
2. And if I try to create a context menu with a `content_scripts` it doesn't work:

   ```
   TypeError: browser.contextMenus is undefined
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that is run in response to a contextMenus event ([`contextMenus.onClicked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/onClicked) listener, or [`onclick` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/create#Parameters) in [`contextMenus.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/create)), you can inject a content script using `tabs.executeScript()` and copy the `document.title` to the clipboard from there. The script could be as simple as just static text which you execute with the `code` property to [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript). The `document.title` is available to the content script. If you want to include data not available to the content script, you will need to: [Pass a parameter to a content script injected using chrome.tabs.executeScript()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815514/3773011).