# Set value active input in active page from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an extension for Chrome. I want when I click on button from my extension, the value 'abc' will be set into active input on active page. 
[image]
Here are my codes:
1) manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "short_name": "Test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version":"2.0.0.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Load EmojiSelector"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js":["content.js"]
    }
    ]
    ,
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

2) index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Test SendMessage</title>
    <script src='content.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='btsend' type='button' value='Send abc to input'>
</body>
</html>
```

3) background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
    var act = chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
        //How to set the value of response to active input in page????
    });
});
```

4) content.js

```
    onload=function(e){
    var btsend = document.getElementById('btsend');
    btsend.onclick = function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('abc');  
    }
}
```

How can I set value for active input in active page by using DOM.

Comment: Assuming you follow wOxxOm's answer, your next issue will probably be covered by: [Pass a parameter to a content script injected using chrome.tabs.executeScript()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17567624)

Comment: This related to my topic, but not suitable. I want to set the value for DOM in active page. And there is just only set value for variable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure to read about the [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): your popup script should be different from the content script. Actually, you don't need an unconditionally injected content script at all, use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) like shown in the official sample extension [Page Redder](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:redder).

   Note: It's not possible to insert text on the default new tab page because Chrome redirects keyboard input to its built-in omnibox (address bar) which accepts only trusted (real) key presses, not the ones sent from JavaScript.
2. The correct popup script should attach a `click` listener to the element
3. You don't need a background page script at all for this task

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version":"2.0.0.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Load EmojiSelector"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<input id='btsend' type='button' value='Send abc to input'>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
```

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById('btsend').onclick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'content.js'});
};
```

content.js:

```
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'abc');
```

Comment: The content script didn't tell me that insert text to where???? I want to insert in to active input on active opened page!!!!!

Comment: NO. Not relate to your codes, and of any above users. So I don't choose the exact answer

Comment: That's mean your code didn't help me in this situation :(

Comment: I tried, no error, but no work!!!! No text was inserted into Input box of google.com

Comment: @HTCom, It works. The code is correct. I've just tried it again on https://www.google.com/ Here's the extension zip https://puu.sh/uLlYH/1805bc9e8a.zip If it doesn't work for you then there's something wrong with your browser maybe (for example you're using ancient version that doesn't support ES6 arrow syntax).

Comment: Note: It's not possible to insert text on the default new tab page because Chrome redirects keyboard input to its built-in omnibox (address bar) which accepts only trusted (real) key presses, not the ones sent from JavaScript.

Comment: I did it successfully. Try this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-from-emoji/papnjoffofhpnddonlobhlhjijjgojmo

Comment: Good. I'm glad.