# ASP.NET doesn't recognize textbox change value by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to set an ASP.NET website textbox but the site doesn't recognize the input from the javascript.
For testing purposes I am using this example [Set value active input in active page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814403/set-value-active-input-in-active-page-from-chrome-extension) with the proper changes to fit my needs.

The issue is that when extension sets the textbox value form is not auto submitted as if I was typing physically the input.

Here are the changes on the content.js

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function demo() {
  document.getElementById('addresses').value = 'π';
  await sleep(200);
  document.getElementById('addresses').value = 'πα';
   await sleep(200);
  document.getElementById('addresses').value = 'παρ';
   await sleep(200);
  document.getElementById('addresses').value = 'παρν';
   await sleep(200);
  document.getElementById('addresses').value = 'παρνα';
}

demo();
//document.getElementById("dnn_ctr654_View_ctxSearchZipCode_btnSearchZipCode").click()
```

I even tried to force the submission of the form but no luck!

Comment: Try using [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) followed by [`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur), maybe that will kick off the auto submit - which doesn't work on every character you type in anyway.

Comment: Not working. Just tried it.

Comment: @Velucio, did you focus the element before execCommand? Also, maybe the page is "smart" and uses contentEditable so a different element should be focused.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I did the focus before and the blur after. also tried to focus write a character blur focus write character blur etc. As for the "smart" I am not sure but I will try to do check it. But its weird because when you write there something manually its working fine. even if you write a single character it works.