# Error when injecting script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a Chrome extension to open a new tab on button click and then execute js in it.

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "author": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "background": {},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","http://*/","https://*/"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="saveBtn">Save</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function(){
  chrome.tabs.create({
    selected:false, 
    url:'https://analytics.google.com/something...'
  },function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file:"jquery.min.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file:"html2canvas.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file:"FileSaver.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:'inject.js'});
  });
});
```

All javascript files are in the same folder. I am getting this error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL at Object.callback (chrome-extension://jamfjopkccgnbpkhafanifhjambepphc/popup.js:8:23)
```

on lines where I am trying to inject jquery.min.js, html2canvas.js and FileSaver.js BUT NOT inject.js! New tab opens correctly, callback is executed but then the error is thrown. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just so we are clear, your URL is correct and not `https://analytics.google.com/something...` ? Because it looks like you're trying to hit a `chrome://` URL : Which you cannot do.

Comment: Also I must refer you to here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600495/chrome-tabs-executescript-cannot-access-a-chrome-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in there.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file:"jquery.min.js"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file:"html2canvas.js"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file:"FileSaver.js"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:'inject.js'});
```

The first three have `tab.ib` instead of `tab.id`, which will pass `undefined`. In this case, Chrome will try to run the script in your current tab, which is probably `chrome://extensions` or something like this.

From the docs:

> integer   (optional) tabId
>   The ID of the tab in which to run the script; **defaults to the active tab of the current window**.

By the way, you might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535233/injecting-multiple-scripts-through-executescript-in-google-chrome) to ensure that your scripts are executed in the right order.

Comment: Yes! I would never notice that ib :D