# Multiple JS Lines in Chrome.Tabs.ExecuteScript()

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that performs some actions based on the button toggle (state 0/1).

The problem is that right now, it changes the color Red/Blue, but there are some other actions that need to happen. I can't find a way to refer to a **separate multi-line script** or file in Chrome.Tabs.ExecuteScript. Every example I've found on the Web only has a single command, which is useless for me! Splitting across lines doesn't work. There will be FOR-loops, IF-statements, and other complexity I want to inject.

Actions needed:
(State=0) Red background, make all IMG tag invisible, etc.
(State=1) Blue background, make all IMG tags visible, etc.

**background.js**

```
var state = 0;

function activate()
{

    if (state == 0)
    {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
          });       

        state = 1;
    }
    else
    {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"'
          });       

        state = 0;
    }

}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(activate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a separate file with your commands, and execute it with

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  file: 'content1.js'
});
```

If you need to pass parameters along, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976996/chromes-tabs-executescript-passing-parameters-and-using-libraries).

---

Alternative solution is to have a single content script and pass commands to it using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

If your approach registers listeners, make sure to execute `addListener` only once.

Comment: MDN is also a good source for documentation and examples :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript